# Apply an effect to many IDs in a page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a loading effect in a button (Bootstrap v.3) which works fine.

```
<a href="#" class="btn  btn-primary" role="button" id="fat-btn" >Read</a>
```

and the **script**

```
       $('#fat-btn').click(function () {
            var btn = $(this)
            btn.button('loading')
            setTimeout(function () {
                btn.button('reset')
            }, 9000)            
        });
```

This works fine! But it is applied only to the first button in my page. What can i do, to apply this effect to more buttons? I thought i could type similar scripts but with different selectors. But this is not convenient, (if i have 20 buttons, i will type 20 different selectors??)

Comment: Ids are unigue. Youcant have many. Use class instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead of [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and assign same class to all buttons which you probably already have.

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function () {
       btn.button('reset');
    }, 9000);            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a common class instead

```
   $('.btn').click(function () {
        var btn = $(this)
        btn.button('loading')
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.button('reset')
        }, 9000)            
    });
```